# Convert chr to date in R, but have same date

Tags: r

I have data like:

```
         date       tot     rat
1  2022-08-04       637090 0.128866
2  2022-08-05      1438100 0.117801
3  2022-08-06      1270188 0.133178
4  2022-08-07      2142400 0.121704
5  2022-09-01      2141110 0.111704
```

I use R studio 4.1.1. column `date` is chr and I want to convert as date. Here's the script I try:

```
library(lubridate)
date_prep <- data %>% 
  mutate(date = ymd(date) %>% as_date()) %>% 
  select(date, tot, rat)
```

but the result:

```
         date        tot      rat
1  2022-08-01       637090 0.128866
2  2022-08-01      1438100 0.117801
3  2022-08-01      1270188 0.133178
4  2022-08-01      2142400 0.121704
5  2022-09-01      2141110 0.111704
```

why the date is same? any suggestion how to convert chr to date?

Comment: Try `date = as.date(date)`.

Comment: You should include the libraries in your example code: `dplyr` and `lubridate`. And you do not need to use `as_date()` after `ymd()`. Having said all that: I cannot reproduce your problem using the example data: the dates were converted as expected.

Comment: can't replicate.  `lubridate::ymd(c("2022-08-04", "2022-08-05", "2022-08-06"))` works just fine

Answer (score 0):

```
data$date = as.POSIXct(data$date, format="%Y-%m-%d")
```

Comment: probably because it's a code only answer with no explanation. These aren't encouraged. Please give a bit of explanation as to why your code works.